# Entity FrameWork Core does not display the value returned through querying

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to display a specific value from a column on the page and I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC with Entity FrameWork Core to do so. The problem which I'm facing that it does not return the the column value, it rather returns some method.

Here's the controller

```
public IActionResult newTicket()
            {
                string getUsername = HttpContext.Session.GetString("username");
                ViewBag.username = _context.users.Where(o => o.username == getUsername).ToList();
    
                return View();
            }
```

So basically what this action should be doing that it should get username from the session first. Then, it should run a query in the database such that if there is a similar username in the database then pass the value of username to the view by using viewbag.
The view

```
<input class="form-control w-50" asp-for="cName" required="required" value="@ViewBag.username"/>
```

This is how the output looks, I don't want it to look like that, I want it to display username.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6dXo.png

If I had to explain what I mean in this question through another language (PHP MySQL) is that.

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection_variable,"SELECT * from complaints 
WHERE username = '$username'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $row['username'];
}
```

This is what I mean, in case I failed to explain you can ask for details.

Comment: EF Core doesn't display anything, it's an ORM. The query loaded a *list of strings*, not just a single string. If you wanted only one result you should use `FirstOrDefault()`, not `ToList()`

Comment: BTW why are you using `ViewBag` instead of passing the result as a ViewModel to the view? With a strongly typed ViewModel you'd have noticed the problem immediately. A ViewBag is dynamic so it allows storing *anything*, whether it's the right type or not

Comment: How to do that? I have recently shifted from PHP so I don't have much idea about it

Comment: By reading the Getting Started tutorials, not jumping into code. Would you just start writing Javascript in an Angular or React project? Wouldn't you try to read the docs and tutorials first, to see how things work?

Comment: As for using another language to explain, you used a loop in PHP too

Comment: Oh, if you mean importing the model to the razor view page. I have already done that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ViewBag use List, not user data.

Use this.

```
public IActionResult newTicket()
{
     string getUsername = HttpContext.Session.GetString("username");
     ViewBag.username = _context.users.Where(o => o.username == getUsername).FirstOrDefault()?.username;
    
     return View();
}
```

Comment: This was the most approachable and easy to understand answer, thanks, it worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do in view something like this:

```
@foreach(User usr in ViewBag.username)
{
<b>@usr.username</b>
}
```

But now what you are doing is just calling the default `ToString()` method of collection. That's why you are getting that result. You should be calling the property of an element in that collection.

Or you can try this:

```
ViewBag.username = _context.users.FirstOrDefault(o => o.username == getUsername);
```

Comment: What if I wanted to do the whole thing on the razor page instead?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing? What exactly do you want to query from database?

Comment: Because you are getting a list from database not a single user object.

Comment: I'm trying make trying to submit some values by default to the form, username and some other columns should be sent along with the form.

Comment: Your code is working but now I'm facing another issue, the session values are not returning anything on the controllers but the sessions are working fine on the razor page, that's why I decided to write the whole query on the razor page.